# Determine whether or not $\neg q \to \neg (q \land (p \to \neg q))$ is a tautology

Tags: logic

I have been trying to solve this but I got stuck at the end.

---

$$\begin{align} \neg q \to \neg (q \land (p \to \neg q)) &\equiv  \neg  \neg q\lor \neg (q \land ( \neg p\lor \neg q)) \\& \equiv q\lor \neg q \land  \neg ( \neg p\lor \neg q) \\&\equiv T \land  \neg ( \neg p\lor \neg q)\end{align}$$

Comment: I'd suggest you think about what $q\to (p\to q)$ *means* and then you think again about the claim in question.

Comment: $(\neg q)\to\neg(q\land\phi)$ is a tautology for *any* $\phi$, and you might find it easier to prove, since you won't be tempted to dig into the details of the $(p\to\neg q)$ part of your formula.

Answer (score 6):

In the second to last step, you commited an error 
\begin{align*}
¬q→¬(q∧(p→¬q))
&\equiv ¬¬q∨¬(q∧(¬p∨¬q))\\
&\equiv q∨¬q\color{red}\lor¬(¬p∨¬q)\\
&\equiv T \color{red}\lor ¬(¬p∨¬q)\\
&\equiv T.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different way to see this

$$\begin{align}\neg q \to \neg (q \wedge (p \to \neg q)) &\color{red}\equiv (q \wedge (p \to \neg q)) \to q \\&\equiv (\neg q \vee  q )\vee \neg( p\to \neg q)\\&\equiv T \vee \neg (\neg p \vee\neg q) \\&\equiv \color {red} T\end{align}$$